# Best way to invoke 'setter method' for first access and 'getter method' for the rest with "getter setter" pattern?

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented, serialization

Here is a json which comes in the request param. I am constructing a class with getter and setter for accessing the values in json so that I could be able to pass the class object to different methods and able to access the member variables in them.

```
public class RequestParams {
    private String student_id;
    private String student_name;
    private String student_role_number;
    private String department_name;
    private String stream;

    private JSONObject studentDetails;

    public RequestParams(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.studentDetails = request.getParameter(“studentdetails”);
    }

    public String getStudentId() {
        if(this.student_id == null) {
            this.setStudentId();
        }
        return this.student_id;
    }
    public String getStudentName() {
        if(this.student_name == null) {
            this.setStudentName();
        }
        return this.student_name;
    }
    public String getRoleNumber() {
        if(this.student_role_number == null) {
            this.setRoleNumber();
        }
        return this.student_role_number;
    }
    public String getDepartmentName() {
        if(this.department_name == null) {
            this.setDepartmentName();
        }
        return this.student_name;
    }
    public String getStream() {
        if(this.stream == null) {
            this.setStream();
        }
        return this.stream;
    }
    public void setStudentId() {
        this.student_id = this.studentDetails.getString("student_id");
    }
    public void setStudentName() {
        this.student_name = this.studentDetails.getString("student_name");
    }
    public void setRoleNumber() {
        this.student_role_number = this.studentDetails.getString("role_number");
    }
    public void setDepartmentName() {
        this.department_name = this.studentDetails.getString("department_name");
    }
    public void setStream() {
        this.stream = this.studentDetails.getString("stream");
    }
}
```

Have the following doubts,

1. Constructing as class object to reference it from different methods - Is this a good one? Am I going wrong?
2. How to organise my getter setter so that only set is called only for the first time and for the next calls the value is returned directly? Is there a better way to avoid the null check each time

> if(this.student_id == null) {
>
> this.setStudentId();
>
> }

3. Is there any advantage of accessing the methods and variables within the class with `this.` ?

PS: I could not invoke all the setter initially from the constructor because all the values declared in the class need not be necessarily present in the json. So, I thought that it would be better if I could initialise the member variable with value during first access.

Comment: I have found your design a little bit convoluted. Why can't you initialize to null those params that are not present in the json object? If they were not during the construction phase, they won't be either during the "setter" call. At the end , in both cases the values will be null.

Comment: @Rajasuba Your question #3 (about `this.`) is already answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class - basically there are some cases when it is required, but other than those, it is mostly a matter of style/preferences and consistency.

Answer (score 6):

Your member variables are redundant. You should either store the `JSONObject` or the `String`s but not both of them. This will avoid consistency issues.

Here is a suggestion:

```
public class RequestParams {
    private final String student_id;
    private final String student_name;
    private final String student_role_number;
    private final String department_name;
    private final String stream;

    public RequestParams(HttpServletRequest request) {
        JSONObject studentDetails = request.getParameter(“studentdetails”);
        this.student_id = studentDetails.getString("student_id");
        this.student_name = studentDetails.getString("student_name");
        this.student_role_number = studentDetails.getString("role_number");
        this.department_name = studentDetails.getString("department_name");
        this.stream = studentDetails.getString("stream");
    }

    public String getStudentId() {
        return this.student_id;
    }
    public String getStudentName() {
        return this.student_name;
    }
    public String getRoleNumber() {
        return this.student_role_number;
    }
    public String getDepartmentName() {
       return this.student_name;
    }
    public String getStream() {
        return this.stream;
    }
}
```

Note that the member variables can be made `final` and the class is immutable now.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.. I would like to add - In my case the json may not contains all the field all the time.. So initializing the class variables with `json.getString` - for the filed that is not there seems to be an overhead.. So, I have opted for lazy initialization method..

Comment: Please suggest me a better approach to handle this..

Comment: @RajasubaSubramanian: Holding the JSONObject for the whole lifetime of the object has probably more overhead than storing the strings. The JSONObject somehow has to store the complete information from the JSON file, including the attribute names.

Comment: ` Holding the JSONObject for the whole lifetime of the object has probably more overhead than storing the strings.`  you are right. But I would like to know how it could cause overhead?

Comment: @RajasubaSubramanian: I was refering to memory usage. The JSONObject is probably implemented as a map of key value pairs. So each entry has two strings. Even if some entries are missing, it probably takes up more memory than the solution I suggested.

Comment: So say for example we have a class which has some 50 variables like `student_name` , `student_id` etc.. and i would receive only 5 to 10 at a time which one would be better?

Comment: either using as a json or using as a class with lazy initialization ? @Frank Puffer

Comment: @RajasubaSubramanian: If you have a class with 50 variables and only 5 to 10 are typically initialized you should re-think your class design. I don't know enough about the context to give a more concrete answer. Maybe you should post a new question and provide more context.

Answer (score 2):

Such initialization approach is called [Lazy initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)

> lazy initialization is the tactic of delaying the creation of an
>   object, the calculation of a value, or some other expensive process
>   until the first time it is needed.

Some languages/platforms provide a standard way to express such a construct (like C#'s [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class), while in others you have to implement it yourself/find some third party library solution.

As far as I can see there is no standard implementation of this pattern in Java, so you can either make a [simple custom one](http://blog.agiledeveloper.com/2015/06/lazy-in-java_24.html), or use one from [popular third-party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23216203/3745022).

Assuming that the chosen lazy implementation is called `Lazy<T>` your class would look like:

```
public class RequestParams {
    private Lazy<String> student_id;

    private JSONObject studentDetails;

    public RequestParams(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.studentDetails = request.getParameter(“studentdetails”);
        this.studentId = new Lazy<String>(() -> this.createStudentId());
    }

    public String getStudentId() {
        return this.student_id.value();
    }

    public String createStudentId() {
        return this.studentDetails.getString("student_id");
    }
}
```

**P.S.:** Do not forget that primitive custom `Lazy<T>` implementation(like the one behind this [link](http://blog.agiledeveloper.com/2015/06/lazy-in-java_24.html)) is not [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), that may or may not be acceptable.

**P.S.1:** Also, I am not exactly sure that it is such a good idea to use `HttpServletRequest` as a constructor parameter - it couples `RequestParams` with http-related classes, that may slightly complicate maintenance and unit-testing, and reduce the possibility of class reuse.

**P.S.2:** While `Lazy<T>` approach is a proper generic solution, in this particular case, where initialization is actually relatively cheap, I'd rather follow the `@Frank Puffer`'s [suggestion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/344430/136796) and fully initialize this class in the constructor, thus making it immutable.